# Handlerbars access Array variable

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, handlebars.js

I'm working with Handlebars in an Express application.
From the server-side I'm passing an array of dates as strings:

```
reqCtrl.dateController = async (req, res) => {
...
var dates = [
    "2020-09-27",
    "2020-09-28",
    "2020-09-29",
    "2020-09-30",
    "2020-10-01",
    "2020-10-02",
    "2020-10-03",
    "2020-10-04",
  ];

  console.log(dates);
  //Resulting in: ['2020-09-27', '2020-09-28', '2020-09-29', '2020-09-30', '2020-10-01', '2020-10-02', '2020-10-03', '2020-10-04']
  res.render("requests/...", 
    dates
  });
}
```

However, on the client side, with the following expression I get different values.

```
<script>
console.log({{ dates }})
//Resulting in:  1984 1983 1982 1981 2009 2008 2007 2006
</script>
```

Am I missing something? How can I render the correctly formatted date?

Comment: The issue was that it was subtracting the numbers rather than showing the string

Answer (score 1):

What would happen if you rendered `<p>{{dates}}</p>`, instead of console logging it? Either way, you will likely want to iterate through arrays to render when using handlebars. This is done with [#each](https://handlebarsjs.com/guide/builtin-helpers.html#each).

```
<ul>
  {{ #each dates}}
    <li>{{this}}</li>
  {{/each}}
</ul>
```